# how do you keep up with all the new frameworks in language X?

Tags: frameworks, programming-languages

Frameworks come and go with all languages and as a developer I am having quite a time trying to:

1. pick a good solid framework in a given language
2. concerned the framework i learn will die and i will have to learn a new framework
3. hate 1,2 because frameworks provide so much out of the box and i hate re-inventing the wheel

Anyone have advice on how to manage the many frameworks for any given language from a developer point of view?

Comment: @the person who voted to close - this is a valid question. The question isn't which framework to use, it's how to avoid being overwhelmed by all the choices.

Comment: @jvenema thanks for the support :-) perhaps this is better for meta though?

Comment: Nah, that's for questions about stackoverflow; it's a good question, don't worry bout it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick one that's good, has solid backing (either open-source or monetarily), and learn it well. If it does the job you need it to do, then it doesn't matter if it "dies", it'll still be doing the job for you.

Comment: For example, Symfony, Cake and now I just discovered kohana (php 5 based) all 3 are php frameworks and I believe all 3 have merit but cannot really commit to one.

Comment: Sure, and there are lots of others too (codeigniter comes to mind). Find one that you enjoy using an does what you need. As long as it solves the problem, that's what matters. Don't get swayed by looks or what other people say - if it solves YOUR problem, it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the two key criteria would be:

a) how good is the documentation? Are there many howto guides and worked examples? Any published books on the framework in question?

b) I would look at the community: join the official mailing lists if there are any; register on forums if there are any. A healthy framework will have plenty of activity in these community resources.

I have worked with several frameworks for web development and now do mobile development. Im curious as to what languages you're looking at?